Why folder structure is not recognized in React app in VScode?
In the following screenshot you can see a basic react app (from a tutorial I attend for learning purposes). Could someone explain why 'import' command is dimmed and apparently not loading the images? On the left you can see the folder structure.

While typing, in the context menu, only the js files of the 'assets' folder appear/


'import' command is dimmed

Because the import not used. You need to remove the quotation marks in src of img:
<img src={logo} alt="" />

